# how to run series of animation on single component in framer-motion in a infinity loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, next.js, framer-motion

I am building a website that uses framer-motion for animation

I have this image component

```
 <motion.img
              ref={scope}
              initial={{ x: -200 }}
              alt="pacman"
              className="absolute z-50"
              src="/pacman.gif"
              width={100}
              height={50}
            />
```

and here it is running a series of animation

```
  const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();

  const runAnimation = async () => {
    await animate(scope.current, { x: 300 }, { duration: 2 });
    await animate(scope.current, { scaleX: -1 }, { duration: 0.2 });
    await animate(scope.current, { x: -200 }, { duration: 2 });
    await animate(scope.current, { scaleX: 1 }, { duration: 0.2 });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    runAnimation();
  }, []);
```

but I don't understand how can I restart this series inifinity times in a loop once the series got completed

Answer (score 0):

```
 // if your component rerendered for some reason runInterval.current will be untouched
 let runInterval = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setInterval>>();

 const startAnimation = () => {
    runInterval.current = setInterval(() => {
      runAnimation();
    // total duration is 4.4s=4400ms
    }, 4400);
    
  };
```

> The setInterval() function is commonly used to set a delay for
> functions that are executed again and again, such as animations. You
> can cancel the interval using clearInterval().

```
 useEffect(() => {
    startAnimation();
    return () => runInterval.current && clearInterval(runInterval.current);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Is that a optimized solution?

Comment: does it work? did u test it

Comment: yes it works but there is 1 problem the first iteration runs after 4400 seconds and for this I simply run runAnimation 1 time inside useEffect

Comment: animation is expensive work.  if you want to render it forever,  it will be very expensive. I cannot think of optimization of above code

Comment: they say if it works, do not touch it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

You can call the `runAnimation` function recursively at the end of the animation series. This way, once all the animations are complete, it will start the animation series again.

```js
const runAnimation = async () => {
    await animate(scope.current, { x: 300 }, { duration: 2 });
    await animate(scope.current, { scaleX: -1 }, { duration: 0.2 });
    await animate(scope.current, { x: -200 }, { duration: 2 });
    await animate(scope.current, { scaleX: 1 }, { duration: 0.2 });
    runAnimation(); // Restart the animation series once completed
};

useEffect(() => {
    runAnimation();
}, []);
```

By doing this, the animation series will run indefinitely in a loop.

Comment: How can I optimise it I tried running it and my website crashes isn't it too expensive query?